# App stuck at blank loading screen on nougat devices

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-7.0-nougat

My app worked just perfectly fine on marshmallow, but since the nougat update the MainActivity just won't launch. It doesn't give me any error, just a blank white screen that you see when launching an app.

**EDIT:**
I managed to reduce the cause to a small piece of code in the MainActivity which gets run in the onCreate function:

```
if((parsedCijferString.isEmpty()) && (parsedHuiswerkString.isEmpty())){
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        String cijferString;
        String roosterString;
        String huiswerkString;
        try {
            cijferString = dataGetterC.getData(som.getGradesUrl());
            parsedCijferString = cijfers.ParseJSON(cijferString);

            roosterString = dataGetterR.getData(som.getTimetableUrl(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            parsedRoosterString = rooster.ParseJSON(roosterString);

            huiswerkString = dataGetterH.getData(som.getHomeworkUrl(14));
            parsedHuiswerkString = huiswerk.ParseJSON(huiswerkString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that only one of the three blocks ("cijferString", "roosterString", "huiswerkString") is able to run, so if I disable 2 other blocks it will run, but not when I leave them all enabled.
The three blocks use another class called DataGetter where I get the data via okHttp:

DataGetter:

```
package com.bettersomtoday.arnedebeer.somtoday;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

class DataGetter {

    private String responseString;
    private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    String getData(String url) throws Exception {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("REQUEST","FAIL");
                responseString = "FAIL";
            }

            @Override public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                responseString = response.body().string();

                Log.i("Response datagetter", responseString);
            }
        });
        //noinspection StatementWithEmptyBody
        while (responseString == null){
            //Do nothing
        }
        return responseString;
    }
}
```

Hope this might clear some things up!

**END OF EDIT**

I don't really have a clue on what information to give so please feel free to ask! For now I'll give you a bit of information that might have to do with the problem.

Comment: does logcat provide any relevant information?

Comment: See updated question for added logcat information

Comment: @MStoner (tagging you in case you didn't notice my response)

Comment: Hi Arne, I received a notification when you posted the logcat originally. I didn't respond because I couldn't see anything either :-(

Comment: @MStoner oh that's too bad, thanks for looking into it though!

Comment: I face the same issue in one of my applications